# How find a specific tag with Simple HTML DOM?

Tags: php, html, xml, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I want to parse (with Simple HTML DOM) the source code of this URL: http://www.jeuxdemots.org/rezo-xml.php?gotermsubmit=Chercher&gotermrel=lampe&output=onlyxml

Specially, I want to find all "rel" tags and print their "type", I tried this:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.jeuxdemots.org/rezo-xml.php?gotermsubmit=Chercher&gotermrel=chien&output=onlyxml');  
foreach($html->find('rel') as $e) 
     echo $e->type . '<br>';
```

But it doesn't work, it displays a blank page.
Can you tell me why?
Is it because DOM doesn't recognize the tag "rel"?
Also, the source code of the URL seems weird to me, it's a mix between HTML and XML...
How can I parse it ?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like a bug. If you switch to [this replacement](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom) it will work.

Comment: Indeed, it was a bug, it works with Advanced Simple DOM! Thank you very much!